# Android WebView, load from cache and attempt to refresh

Tags: java, android, android-webview, swiperefreshlayout

I am trying to create a small app that loads a webpage and stores it in the cache. When swiping refresh it must attempt to update, but if there is no internet access it should keep the current version.

Currently, I've got "swipe to force refresh" and "load from the cache" working, but can not seem to figure out how to "attempt to refresh if possible".

```
swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipe);
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
        new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                myWebView.clearCache(true);
                myWebView.reload();
            }
        }
);

WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAppCachePath(getBaseContext().getCacheDir().getPath());
webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);

myWebView.loadUrl(config.getString("website_root"));
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        if (!swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: What do mean by "attempt to refresh if possible" ? You mean retry after sometime?

Comment: At this moment on launch, it will load from cache and if cache does not exist it will load from network 

I want it so that when it loads it will load from cache, and if there is network access, attempt to fetch a more updated version of the page. if it succeeds cool, load it. if not too bad, better luck next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK) for `WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK`:

> Use cached resources when they are available, even if they have
>   expired. Otherwise load resources from the network

Because of this you view is always loaded from cache.

You can use following method:
1. Check connectivity:

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
}
```

2. Before instead of setting:

   ```
   WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
   webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
   webSettings.setAppCachePath(getBaseContext().getCacheDir().getPath());

   webSettings.setCacheMode(isNetworkConnected()?WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE: WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
   ```
3. On Swipe to refresh, you can do the same:

   ```
   swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
           new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
               @Override
               public void onRefresh() {
                   if(isNetworkConnected()){
                       ...
                       myWebView.reload();
                   } else {
                         //Do something for non-connectivity
                   }
           }
       });
   ```

Comment: Your way to use is wrong. It's unnecessery to load the website every time not from the cache. In general, caching is a good thing the solution is to use:webSetting.setCacheMode(WebSetting.LOAD_DEFAULT)